# Sesion activa en API REST

Tags: php, session

Necesito conocer si una sesión está activa o no. Dispongo de tres páginas `.php`:

-Administracion.php

-Comparador.php

-App.php

La página App.php tiene un formulario de acceso que se conecta a la aplicación mediante una petición `AJAX`. Hasta ahora puedo ver las tres páginas con la ruta de cada una sin problema. Lo que quiero es comprobar en Administracion.php y en Comparador.php si se ha iniciado sesión antes en la página App.php
En el caso de que haya una sesión activa si se puede entrar a las páginas secundarias pero si no hay ninguna sesión activa, no me tiene que dejar entrar en las páginas secundarias. Al intentar entrar en las páginas secundarias debe redirigirme a la página principal.

Al escribir el código `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {window.location='App.php'}` en las páginas secundarias obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Alguna idea?

[image: Error con los cambios de la respuesta]

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {
$em = getEntityManager();
    $args = $request->getParsedBody() ?? json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
    $user = $em->getRepository(Usuario::class)->findOneByUsername($args['username']);

    if (null == $user) {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('No existe ese usuario'); window.location='index.html'</script>" ;

    } else {
        if ($user->getPassword() == $args['password']){
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user->getId();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user->getUsername();
            if($user->getAdmin() && $user->getEnabled()){
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='Administracion.php'</script>" ;
            } else if($user->getEnabled()){
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='Comparador.php'</script>" ;
            } else {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Su cuenta no está activada'); window.location=''</script>" ;
            }

        } else {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Contraseña incorrecta'); window.location='App.php'</script>" ;
        }
    }
});
```

La clase Usuario tiene un atributo llamado username, lo he estado utilizando sin problema antes de añadir a cada página secundaria el código de la respuesta.

Comment: Una API REST no debe guardar nunca estado, debe de ser "stateless". O sea que la pregunta estaría mal formulada. No sería API Rest

Comment: Sin API REST como puedo controlar si la sesión está activa?

Comment: Hombre, poder puedes hacerlo, pero una API Rest no debe de guardar estado entre peticiones, se le pide al API que haga algo (por ejemplo que te devuelva los datos de un recurso GET /clientes) y cuando te devuelve algo acaba la sesión. No sé si lo que tu quieres es hacer un API o qué.

Comment: Tengo un API hecho ya, solo me falta controlar las sesiones... Y según me lo han pedido parece ser que lo quieren así. El código php que pongo al inicio de las páginas secundarias no es correcto?

Comment: ¿puedes hacer un echo session_status() y decirnos que devuelve? es posible que esté retornando un valor númerico, en cuyo caso 2 equivaldría a sesión activa. Y window.location es javascript, no lo llamas adecuadamente y provocas un error 500

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado `session_status()` puede devolver tambien un valor numérico.

> PHP_SESSION_DISABLED si las sesiones están deshabilitadas.
>
> PHP_SESSION_NONE si las sesiones están habilitadas, pero no existe ninguna.
>
> PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE si las sesiones están habilitadas, y existe una.
>
> _DISABLED = 0
>   _NONE = 1
>   _ACTIVE = 2

http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-status.php

Y además debes llamar adecuadamente al cambio de localización si vas a usar `javascript`.

```
    <?php if (session_status() != "PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE" && session_status() != 2) { ?> 
         <script>window.location='App.php'</script>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: Si añado el código anterior a cada página secundaria obtengo un error en la petición AJAX del login. Adjunto arriba el código de dicha petición y el error.

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar la solución, ves algo raro en mi código Carmen?

Comment: Puede ser porque esté ejecutándose a pesar de no tener sesión activa. Prueba a ejecuatar el restante código de las páginas secundarias en la condición else del if que busca la falta de sesión activa a ver si funciona.

Comment: Puedes abrir un chat para hablar mejor?

Comment: Ahora no puedo, lo siento pero hoy me pillas fatal de tiempo

Comment: ok, cuando puedas abres chat si quieres. Sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Si inicias todos los script php con la siguiente linea?

```
Administracion.php
require "..haysesion.php";
...

-Comparador.php
require "..haysesion.php";
...

-App.php
require "..haysesion.php";
...


haysesion.php
Si no hay sesion -> die;
```

pseudocodigo:

haysesion.php

```
<?php
if !hayunasesioniniciada() {
   echo "no hay";
   die:
   (en ajax)
  json_enconde(array('error' => 1));
  die;
  o redirigir...
  header("Location: dom.com");
  die;
}
```

aqui termina el programa si no encuentra un die; el programa continua 
 normalmente luego de la llamada del requiere.

Comment: no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres con haysesion.php ese archivo que debería contener? Yo inicio sesión en el archivo App.php. He probado a poner en Administracion.php y Comparador.php require App.php pero tampoco es la solución

Comment: si haysesion.php verifica sesion y si hay una sesion iniciada, la ejecucion continua luego del require, en caso contrario termina el programa (si usas ajax, el prg. termina con un json_encode...). Mi sugerencia es que todos los php llamen a haysesion.php en la primera linea. haysesion.php deberia contener solo el codigo que verifica si hay o no una sesion iniciada y nada mas.

Comment: Esa no es la solución, sigo teniendo el error que comenté ayer